# how to sort array in node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have below structure of array.

```
{
    "a": "aa",
    "**b**": {
        "**b**": "bb",
        "c": 1
    },
    "d": "d"
},
```

I want to display the end result like below.

```
{ "a": "aa",
        "b": "bb",
        "c": 1
    "d": "dd"
},
```

I am trying with below code but its not working as expected.

```
let finalArr = [];
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(resObj)) {
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      for (let [keyInternal, valueInternal] of Object.entries(value)) {
        valueInternal.map(arrValue => {
          const finalObj = {
            a: '',
            b: '', 
            c : '',       
            d : ''
          };
          finalObj.a = key;
          finalObj.b = arrValue[1].b;
          finalObj.c = arrValue[1].c;
          finalObj.d = keyInternal;
          finalArr.push(finalObj);
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: _"I have below structure of array"_ - That's an object and not an array.

Comment: Do you want to flatten a nested object? Is `"d": "dd"` a typo?

Comment: What's with the comma after the objects?

Comment: Yes. I want to flatten nested object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to flatten you object something like this

```js
let obj = {
  "a": "aa",
  "**b**": {
    "**b**": "bb",
    "c": 1,
  },
  "d": "d",
  "*e*": {
    "**e**": {
      "e": 2
    }
  }
}

let flatten = (obj, final = {}) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      flatten(value, final)
    } else {
      final[key] = value
    }
  })
  return final
}

console.log(flatten(obj))
```

Comment: This function giving me only 1st value in object. I have multiple values in object.

Comment: @Nilesh what do you mean by that ? can you post an example of that ?

Comment: for example I have such object.  var obj = [ {
    "a": "aa",
    "**b**": {
        "**b**": "bb",
        "c": 1
    },
    "d": "d"
},{
    "a": "aa",
    "**b**": {
        "**b**": "bb",
        "c": 1
    },
    "d": "d"
},{
    "a": "aa",
    "**b**": {
        "**b**": "bb",
        "c": 1
    },
    "d": "d"
}] . If I use above function its returning only last object  in expected format not all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` on entries and build new object. if the value is object then use `Object.assign` to flatten.

```js
const obj = {
  a: "aa",
  b: {
    b: "bb",
    c: 1
  },
  d: "d"
};

const flatten = obj => {
  const res = {};
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === "object") {
      Object.assign(res, value);
    } else {
      res[key] = value;
    }
  });
  return res;
};

console.log(flatten(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using below way.

```
         let finalArr = [];
          for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(resObj)) {
            if (typeof value === 'object') {
              for (let [keyInternal, valueInternal] of Object.entries(value)) {
                valueInternal.map(arrValue => {
                  const finalObj = {
                    a: '',
                    d: ''
                  };
                  finalObj.a= key;
                  finalObj.d= keyInternal;
                  var tempobj = {...finalObj,...arrValue};
                  finalArr.push(tempobj);
                });
              }
            } 
          }
```